# Was there a part 2 to Ralph Bakshi's Lord of the Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Is there any production footage of part 2 of Ralph Bakshi's *Lord of The Rings* 70's animated movie? At the end of the film there is dialogue indicating that there would be another film:

> **Narrator:** As their gallant battle ended, so too ends the first great tale of [*The Lord of the Rings.*](https://youtu.be/ha2CnLUSfWQ?t=247)

Was such a film produced?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently a lack of funding did not allow for a part 2.

> By the time The Hobbit aired in 1977, Bakshi had already spent three years creating his Tolkien adaptation based on The Fellowship of the Ring and The Two Towers, the first two installments in the the three-part The Lord of the Rings book series. **Bakshi had intended to film a sequel to his movie, but it never materialized due to a lack of financing**.
>
> <sub>[One made-for-TV movie to underwhelm them all, Galliot](https://theoutline.com/post/2495/lord-of-the-rings-return-of-the-king-cartoon-history?zd=2&zi=efkobkm5)</sub>

Most of the animated film suffered from a lack of financing as well, so it is no surprise they didn't make a sequel.

> "Where I do think the movie suffers, even taking into account the low budget and rapid schedule, are the big battle scenes, especially at Helm’s Deep."
>
> <sub>[SCHLOCK & AWE: RALPH BAKSHI’S THE LORD OF THE RINGS, Anderson](https://nerdist.com/schlock-awe-ralph-bakshis-the-lord-of-the-rings/)</sub>

Comment: They didn't even have time or money to finish the rotoscoping for the first film, much less film the second.

Comment: Thanks, think I remember something about Tolkien helping with the screenplay but died and his son Christopher taking over but might have dreamed it. Just have to live with Wizards I suppose

Comment: There is a sort-of sequel made for TV in 1980 by Rankin & Bass, entitled Return of the King (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079802/). Rankin and Bass also did an animated Hobbit movie in 1977 (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077687/)

Comment: Thanks Klaus, don't know what I hadn't seen the Rankin & Bass ones? They look much more mad for kids against Bakshi's LoTRs. It would be great to see a gritty version of RoTK

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - The Rankin/Bass The Return of the King was intended purely as a sequel for the Rankin/Bass The Hobbit, and began production prior to the Ralph Bakshi Lord of the Rings.